# Of Swing and AWT, why is one considered light-weight and the other heavy-weight?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Why is it said that Swings is heavy-weight and AWT is light-weight in JAVA?

Comment: Since you may have mixed up which is called heavy-weight and which is called light-weight, I left the title ambiguous.  Please do let us know if Denis Troller's answer does answer your question.

Comment: AFAIK one of design goals of SWT was to have less resource-consuming framework than Swing thus SWT uses native wiggets (and thus hopefully less memory and CPU time for drawing). But today (more than 10 years later) you would hardly notice difference in this regard. Funnily enough http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Widget_Toolkit also contains this ambiguity.

Comment: Maybe this answer your question http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Why_does_Eclipse_use_SWT%3F

Answer (score 14):

AWT is said to be "Heavyweight" because basically each AWT component is a native platform component. AWT is implemented on top of the platform's native GUI toolkit.
This also explains why AWT was pretty limited compared to Swing. It uses the least common denominator as far as what is implemented.

Swing, on the other hand, is implemented in Java for pretty much everything except for top level components (windows...). There can be native components and those are still termed "heavy weight".

Take a look at [this page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/grid/library/os-swingswt/) from IBM for an in-depth comparison of AWT, Swing and SWT.

EDIT: I assume that was your question, even though heavy/light seem to be reversed in your phrasing. Heavy/light weight is pretty much a standard denomination in the Java GUI toolkits so I went with my understanding. (thanks to BobbyShaftoe for pointing that out).

Comment: I see, perhaps the questioner is confused as the question states that Swing is considered Heavyweight not AWT.

Comment: Woops true. Well he either made a mistake or was talking about something else, but since the terms "heavyweight" end "lightweight" are pretty much standard on this topic, I'd go with the mistake. If the answer is not what he was looking for, he'll let us know.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. it's interesting nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

In the Java world, AWT components are considered "heavy-weight" because they use underlying native components. When you instantiate an instance of **java.awt.Button**, you are actually asking the underlying OS to paint this object for you.

Swing, on the other hand, is "light-weight" because it mostly depends on the Java2D API to do all painting, which in turn delegates to the underlying OS or hardware. This also explains why Swing needs all those UI components that do the actual painting to mimic a specific look and feel (Windows, GTK, Motif, etc.).

[This article explains more in detail the difference between light-weight and heavy-weight components.](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Because each "heavyweight" component has a native peer, and "lightweight" components do not. Since AWT is heavyweight, each AWT Button has a corresponding MFC button on the windows platform, or Motif button on a Unix platform. Since Swing is lightweight, the graphics of the button is just drawn on top of the frame... there is no underlying MFC or Motif button. You can find more information on this topic in the article [Mixing heavy and light components](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/index.html) on Sun's website.

Answer (score -1):

I don't totally understand the question and I'm sure this is going to result in a flamewar but perhaps it is because AWT provides a "simpler" API, though it is a bit more primitive. Swing however, is arguably a very top-heavy, or heavy weight, if you like API. It has far richer support and many more classes than AWT.

Comment: true as well, Swing is much more complicated because of its view/model  structure.